# using proxy with selenium webdriver firefox in python not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, proxy

I would like to make a program that modifies my ip when I go to consult a site with selenium, I use webdriver firefox, unfortunately the site that I use for my tests returns my ip and not the ip that I indicated in the options, could you tell me the error please.

The program launches and the firefox page opens (I don't use headless for the test), but it's my ip that is returned and not the one from the specified proxy.
here is my program

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
proxy = f'{"137.74.65.101"}:{"80"}'

options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')


driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
```

Comment: Why is `proxy` an f-string?

Comment: this argument `proxy-server` is for Chrome, firefox would be `network.proxy.type` , `network.proxy.http` and `network.proxy.http_port` refer [source](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries)

Comment: also, https://httpbin.org/ip disallows tunneling, so the proxy might not work without some more tweaks!